# GitHub Navigating from a repository to my fork of the repository

Tags: github

If I am in one of my organization's repository and I want to navigate to my fork of that repository, the only way I know how to do that is:

click my avatar -> profile -> Repositories -> search for repository

I feel like there ***HAS*** to be an easier way.

I thought I was the only one to experience this problem until my whole team expressed the same frustration by a very simple thing on GitHub.

This question is relevant here because it discusses a programming tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just click on `Fork` (the symbol, not the number), this should appear:

[image]

Only 2 clicks in total.